# PowerBI Matrix with Year and Month

Tags: date, matrix, powerbi

In the matrix below I have data from Jan 2020-Jan 2021, where the Jan column has the data from both 2021 and 2021. Is there any way to have the matrix add another column for Jan 2021 instead of aggregating that in with the Jan 2020 data?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chose Year and Month in the date hierarchy column and then in the matrix click "expand all down one level in the hierarchy.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am new to Power BI and I was wondering recently myself about something similar.
You can create a new column (text format) and combine month and year.

| Date | Date Modified |
| --- | --- |
| dd-MM-yyyy | yyyy-MM |

or

| Date | Date Modified |
| --- | --- |
| dd-MM-yyyy | yyyy-MM (MMMM) |

or

| Date | Date Modified |
| --- | --- |
| dd-MM-yyyy | yyyy-MM (MMM) |

It is not the most elegant solution, it changes a bit what is displayed (not simply months in the headers), it has a few disadvantages but it works.

I would be curious myself whether a better solution exists.

Answer (score 0):

If you click on the date column you are using [InvoiceDate] and select the date option, it will separate out the two date values.

currently it is in a hierarchy showing just the month values but not the actual date

Answer (score 0):

i have this but mine stays summed up at the year level even though the 'month' is expanded under the TimeByDay...
If I take out the year it will provide it like above but combines both... or as is it puts columns in the year

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to do this way:

- Put Years and Months in the columns
- Right click on the matrix > Expand to next level

[image]